# Limitations of CodeIgniter

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter

What are the limitations that can be faced with codeigniter. I know my question is very broad but I wanted to know from the experts if there are any specific limitations.

This is because for my website I want to have visual representation like google maps. The steps which have to be visually displayed. Can the codeigniter handle everything or are there any limitations?

Comment: What are the limitations of PHP?

Comment: limitations would be probably its not pure objected oriented and not as fast as C/C++. I am still open to know more limitations.

Comment: Codeigniter is written in php, so obviously anything you can do in php you can do in Codeigniter. You should give some examples. Codeigniter is not going to `handle everything` however, you will need to do a lot of the work yourself. I'm pretty sure it can "handle" google maps ;)

Comment: Is there any very good advanced codeigniter book that is available in the market. I have a book which is very simple and does not cover much.

Comment: I'm sure CodeIgniter will do whatever you are thinking of, you just need to now how to code it :-)

Comment: Not sure why everyone is marking this guy down. It's a fair question, although a bit broad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is not what limitations CodeIgniter has, it's when does implementing something break outside the local use of the framework.

CodeIgniter is written in PHP, therefore your limitations really are the limitations of PHP itself.

The part to consider though is that if you're spending most of your time working around the paradigms put forth in CodeIgniter then the platform is probably not for you.

**On a second note**

The limitations also are greatly dependant on your skill & resources. It's not strictly the platform that'll prevent someone from achieving thier intended result.

Comment: Great answer. A lot of people beat around the bush, but when it comes down to it... it really just depends on how and what you use it for. +1